# Magento2 UI Component admin Grid / Listing stuck loading

Tags: admin, grid, uicomponent, magento2.3

This is the first **CRUD module** (called **Sinapsis_Store**, for code understanding) I am trying to write in Magento2. I have followed different ways for it, going step by step, trying to understand every new piece of code in module. This project is Magento 2.3.0 CE

I was able to get module **Grid** work using Blocks approach (very similar to Magento1). Next step was the **Edit** form, for that I followed UI Components approach & got it working in a short time, so I came back to the **Grid** part, but surely I am missing something (or lot of things). The grid page loads with no errors, but the page is stuck `"Loading..."`

This is my component for Edit form (very simple, just with one single field right now: `name`)

**app/code/Sinapsis/Store/view/adminhtml/ui_component/store_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">store_form.store_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">store_form.store_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">store_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Sinapsis\Store\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Sinapsis\Store\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Sinapsis\Store\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\SaveButton</item>
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">Sinapsis\Store\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="store_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Sinapsis\Store\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">store_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">store_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">store_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" path="*/*/save" xsi:type="url"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="store_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store Details</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The dataProvider class for this is very simple

**app/code/Sinapsis/Store/Model/DataProvider.php**

```
<?php
namespace Sinapsis\Store\Model;
use Sinapsis\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

    protected $_loadedData;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $employeeCollectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->_loadedData)) {
            return $this->_loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $store) {
            $this->_loadedData[$store->getId()] = $store->getData();
        }
        return $this->_loadedData;
    }
}
```

And here is the last try for Grid component... I have tried several ways for the dataProvider class, but none of them worked

**app/code/Sinapsis/Store/view/adminhtml/ui_component/store_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="context" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context</argument>
        <argument name="namespace" xsi:type="string">store_grid</argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">store_grid.store_grid_listing_data_source</item>
            </item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">store_grid.store_grid_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">store_grid_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Add new store</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/create</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="store_grid_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Sinapsis\Store\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">store_grid_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">store_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">store_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="store_grid_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="store_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Store Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Reading this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_data_source.html, and as you can see in the code my last try is using same class as the one I use in Edit form, as that class does extend **\Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider** so I added a `getDataSourceData()` method

> To make the data available in javascript, add a getDataSourceData()
>   method to the UI component’s PHP class and return
>   $this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->getData(). This will output
>   the result of the data provider’s getData() method into the JSON that
>   is sent to the browser along with the rest of the UI component’s
>   configuration

But again, same result... grid is stuck `"Loading..."`

So, any tips? Maybe the problem is not in dataProvider, but in another piece of XML code in the component?

Comment: try looking in the ajax calls made when the grid is rendered. Maybe one of them shows an error

Comment: No errors there, all HTML & XHR requests give 200

Comment: XML's are pretty hard to debug. I suggest recreating your extension (but don't install the new extension you create) using this tool: https://github.com/UltimateModuleCreator/umc/ and see the differences between your xml and the one that is generated.

Comment: Good point, I'll try & give feedback later. Thanks

Comment: Well... it is hard to explain in a comment (and very dense to explain in a response), but I got it working. Thank you very much @Marius

Comment: you're welcome. You should at least try in a few words to explain it in an answer. It might help others.

Comment: Sure @Marius I'll do

Comment: Maybe you'd want to give a look at this https://github.com/UltimateModuleCreator/umc/issues/16 Marius

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will take a look but it may take a while.

Comment: seems missed Spiner element same issue with fix - [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50827353/1266559](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50827353/1266559)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this following [Marius♦](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius) advice

I created a module with same requirements with https://github.com/UltimateModuleCreator/umc & compared related files

XML format is not the same (this new version is kindly more human readable), so it can be hard to find the differences, but I paste the working **app/code/Sinapsis/Store/view/adminhtml/ui_component/store_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sinapsis_store_manager_grid.sinapsis_store_manager_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="add">
                <url path="*/*/new"/>
                <class>primary</class>
                <label translate="true">Add New Store</label>
            </button>
        </buttons>
        <spinner>sinapsis_store_store_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>sinapsis_store_manager_grid.sinapsis_store_manager_grid_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="sinapsis_store_manager_grid_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <storageConfig>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">store_id</param>
            </storageConfig>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" name="sinapsis_store_manager_grid_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>store_id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>store_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <templates>
                    <filters>
                        <select>
                            <param name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</param>
                            <param name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</param>
                        </select>
                    </filters>
                </templates>
            </settings>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="delete">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected Stores?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Delete Store</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="sinapsis_store/store/massDelete"/>
                    <type>delete</type>
                    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="edit">
                <settings>
                    <callback>
                        <target>editSelected</target>
                        <provider>sinapsis_store_manager_grid.sinapsis_store_manager_grid.sinapsis_store_store_columns_editor</provider>
                    </callback>
                    <type>edit</type>
                    <label translate="true">Edit</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="sinapsis_store_store_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="sinapsis_store/store/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">store_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sinapsis_store_manager_grid.sinapsis_store_manager_grid.sinapsis_store_store_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sinapsis_store_manager_grid.sinapsis_store_manager_grid.sinapsis_store_store_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <settings>
                <indexField>store_id</indexField>
                <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
                <resizeDefaultWidth>55</resizeDefaultWidth>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="store_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="name">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Store name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Sinapsis\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\StoreActions">
            <settings>
                <indexField>store_id</indexField>
                <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

This change required to create & modify some other files, of course, but answering the question, the key would be: trying to use the same class as **DataProvider** for both a grid & edit form UI components was a little barbarity. I paste here some part (as you'll see in the class, that required to create a new class for **CollectionProviderInterface**, etc etc...) of working code

The **DataProvider** referenced in above XML was now defined in **app/code/Sinapsis/Store/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sinapsis_store_manager_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">SinapsisStoreStoreGridCollection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="SinapsisStoreStoreGridCollection" type="Sinapsis\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="model" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Sinapsis\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store</argument>
            <argument name="idFieldName" xsi:type="string">store_id</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">sinapsis_store_store_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">store_collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

And the class... **app/code/Sinapsis/Store/Model/CollectionProvider.php**

```
<?php
namespace Sinapsis\Store\Model\Store;

use Sinapsis\Store\Ui\Provider\CollectionProviderInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Sinapsis\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\CollectionFactory;

class CollectionProvider implements CollectionProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    private $filter;
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * CollectionRetriever constructor.
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->filter            = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb
     */
    public function getCollection()
    {
        return $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
    }
}
```

For other users trying to do the same, I would recommend directly creating the module with that tool, and then go step by step trying to get the purpose of relevant code / files

Comment: much helpful, thanks